# likelihood ratio test with combined likelihood function

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

I have a combined likelihood function:
 $$L(\alpha,\tau)=ce^{-(n+m)\alpha - m\tau}\alpha^{n\bar x}(\alpha+\tau)^{m\bar y}  $$

$$            H_0:\tau=0, H_1:\tau\neq0       $$

Construct the test statistics for a maximum likelihood ratio test of $H_0$ versus
$H_1$. If $n = 20, \bar x = 100, m = 30 \; and \;\bar y = 105$, use an asymptotic result to
carry out the hypothesis test at the 5% significance level.

I am finding it difficult to approach this question and some assistance would be great thank you.

Comment: What *exactly* is your difficulty?

Comment: im not too sure how to start the question i know about the ratio where if the alternative divided by the null is greater than some constant we reject the null